# Can the Crimson and Corruption in Terraria spread through background walls?

Tags: terraria

The title is basically my question.

I've use TEdit to remove all of the stone and dirt Crimson in my world, but the background walls don't seem to be removed by TEdit.

Will these wall blocks make the Crimson spread in my world still, or am I safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, walls cannot spread anything. Blocks of certain types within a small enough range (3 or less blocks I believe) can be converted by Crimson/Corruption/Hallow, with a handful of special exceptions related to flora in the Corruption, and the beginning of [Hardmode](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode#Spread).

In the next section on that same link one can also find this relevant gem:

> Each time an Altar is destroyed, there is a 66% chance that a single random tile in the caverns layer will be converted to Ebonstone/Crimstone or Pearlstone, facilitating the spread of underground Hallow or Corruption/Crimson. Only stone blocks can be converted in this way.

So ensure you either kill all Altars in your world that you don't plan on keeping (protect the one(s) you want to keep, it is important to have at least one) or ensure you scour your entire caverns layer each time to kill an Altar.

Comment: So the small bit of extra crimson that I found isn't from a wall block?

Comment: One thing I can remember, is that whenever you smash Altars in the Crimson or Corruption, that it also randomly converts a small chunk somewhere on the map to Crimson/Corruption. Same type of "random conversion" that occurs upon entering Hardmode as it adds the Hallow to your world.

Comment: There's diminishing returns on how much ore is generated when you smash a lot of altars. I usually stop after three ore cycles (9 altars).

Comment: Well sure, however diminished returns are still returns, and the upside of clearing out "extras" from the already finite set means one can terraform with more uniformity, but that's all this or that and isn't exactly important either way haha

Comment: I haven't smashed any altars yet, I'm avoiding that.